# iOS How to select row, when a person selects the UITextField inside it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

So I have a `UITableView`, where all cells have a `UITextField` in them as a subview with a `tag=1`. What's troubling me is that I want when a user clicks on a textField and edits it to know on which row has that happened. What I think can solve it, is to make the cell select itself when the subview (`UITextField`) is selected. How can I achieve that?

I tried with an array, but because cells are reused, it wouldn't work. Looping through all of the rows would be simply too slow.

Comment: Tried with Uitextfield delegate method..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textfield.superview.superview` gives you the cell instance.
Use the delegate to get the action

Comment: It's better to not use `superview` for such tasks. Especially in cascade. Just because you need some checks for class of the superview and there are some much simpler ways to do the job.

Comment: @AndreyChevozerov : why ? Why need some check for that? Why cant it use superview?

Comment: I agree with @AndreyChevozerov on using superview in cascade, and your answer in particularly risky as there is no insurance that the `UITextField` will only be two levels down in the cell (one could have embedded it in multiple subviews).

Comment: Thanks, it works this way, but only with one superview. I was able to get the indexPath in the textFieldShouldReturn method like this:
NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)textField.superview];

Comment: The one who embed is the one who writes the code,i think .So it is easily managable by him.and yeah it is him to implement it properly.I give it superview twice because normally it has a content view inside the cell

Answer (score 2):

Disable the `UITextField` in each of your cells by default and use your `UITableView` delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to

1. Store the indexPath of the selected row in a property
2. Enable the `UITextField`
3. Make the `UITextField` first responder

Define the property in your class extension:

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *activeIndex;
@end
```

In your implementation of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    self.activeIndex = indexPath;
    AddCell *selectedCell = (AddCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedCell.textField setEnabled:YES];
    [selectedCell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

You'll want to disable the `UITextField` again when it resigns its first responder status.

Assuming your `UITableViewController` is the delegate for each `UITextField`, you can do this in your implementation of the `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [textField setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is to convert the textFields bounds so it is relative to the tableView, and then use the origin of this rect to get the indexPath.

```
CGRect rect = [self.tableView convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rect.origin];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) to know when the user start editing a `UITextField` (with [`textFieldDidBeginEditing:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW4)).

Two solutions then:

**Solution 1**: Subclass your cell and make it the delegate of the `UITextField`.

Then in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` of your custom cell, make the cell selected:

```
// MyCustomCell.m
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self setSelected:YES animated:YES];
}
```

**Solution 2**: Make the view controller the `UITextField` delegate, and select the right cell from there.

```
// MyTableViewController.m
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Find the cell containing our UITextField
    UIView *cell = textField.superview;
    while (![cell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
    {
        cell = cell.superview;
    }

    // Make the cell selected
    [(UITableViewCell *)cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
}
```

I'd recommend the first solution, as Andrey Chevozerov said in the comments of one of the answers:

> It's better to not use superview for such tasks. Especially in cascade.

Comment: The second solution ? Yes, that's why I quoted you ;). I wouldn't worry much of performances here tough, I don't think it is too bad (just following pointers and doing `isa` comparisons here I think).

Answer (score 0):

Code below will return NSIndexPath.This can be written in **UITextField delegate** -

```
[tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:textField.superview.superview.frame.origin];
```

Try above line your code.

Comment: Using the coordinate to retrieve the cell. Wow. That's terribly unsafe imo. And nothing guarantees that `textfield.superview.superview` will return the cell. The textfield could be embeded in mutiple subviews.

Answer (score -2):

Why you're using tags for textfields?
The proper way is:

1. create custom class for cell;
2. make an outlet for your `UITextField`;
3. when creating cells assign your view controller as a delegate for the cell's text field;
4. assign a tag == `indexPath.row` to the corresponding cell's text field;
5. in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` place a code for selecting cell:

   [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textfield.tag inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];

Comment: ...Apple do actually document both approaches. They're equally correct. For very small projects, tags can save you time. Of course, they're also fragile, so for many people custom cells are the best option (especially here, where you can use the text field delegate). But again, it's not *incorrect* to use tags.

Comment: What if there is 2 or more seciton on the tableview?

Comment: When you have more then one sections you could code the section number in the tag. It's not a big problem.

Comment: Yes, Apple documented both approaches. But I'm not sure they are equal. And my experience tells me that some documented approaches are not as good as they seems to be.